# How to have a Chakra UI icon button that shows text from a certain breakpoint up?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

With Chakra UI, I'd like to create an icon button that only has a text from the 'md' breakpoint up. I've read the docs for the `<Button />` and `<IconButton />` component and this doesn't seem possible by default, because the `<IconButton />` never allows text at all; while the `<Button />` component does allow text, so I could do something like this:

```
<Button leftIcon={ <EmailIcon /> } iconSpacing={ isMd ? 1 : 0 }>{ isMd ? 'Email' : '' }</Button>
```

but the size of the button when there's no text is a bit off and doesn't equal that of a simple `<IconButton />` (eg. when the `<IconButton />` produces a perfectly round button, the above code doesn't).

In the end, I could of course do:

```
isMd ? <Button leftIcon={ <EmailIcon /> }>Email</Button> : <IconButton icon={ <EmailIcon /> } />
```

but I just wanted to check that this is not actually possible using just one component directly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using md, you could use `window.innerWidth`

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  }, []);
```

and then after setting windowWidth you could write something like:

```
(windowWidth < 1420) ? <p>Small<p/> : <p>Big</p>
```

But i would not recommend using `isMd`, its better to use something like:

```
<Text
    fontSize={{ sm: "lg", lg: "xl" }}
    ms={{ sm: "8px", md: "0px" }}>
    {name}
</Text>
```